# Adding Polylines into a Google Maps Data Layer

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my application I am loading a GeoJSON file into Google maps. The file loads correctly without issue, but I wish to apply additional styling that is native to the polyline object rather than the Feature object. What I am trying to do is style the linestring to include multiple icons and a dashed line. I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802664/format-geojson-linestring-to-dashed/28804071) regarding GeoJSON and dashed lines and it works, but I do not want the polylines to be single entities; I want the rendered polylines to reside in one object (data layer). Is what I am trying to achieve possible? Is there a workaround available?

** UPDATE **

I used the code from geocodezip and modified to work as a factory, with two types: marker and polyline.

```
function LayerFactory() {
this.entities = [];
this.labelLayerName = "";
}

LayerFactory.prototype.layerType = PolylineLayer;
LayerFactory.prototype = new google.maps.MVCObject();
LayerFactory.prototype.changed = function (key) {
    if (this.entities) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.entities.length; i++) {
            this.entities[i].overlay.set(key, this.get(key));
        }
    }
};
LayerFactory.prototype.addEntity = function (entity) {
    this.entities.push(entity);

    if (this.layerType === PolylineLayer) {
        for (var i = 0; i < entity.overlays.length; i++) {
            var overlay = entity.overlays[i];
            //add events here
        }
    }
    else if (this.layerType === MarkerLayer) {
        //add events here
    }
};
LayerFactory.prototype.setMap = function (map) { this.set('map', map); };
LayerFactory.prototype.getMap = function () { return this.get('map'); };
LayerFactory.prototype.createLayer = function (options) {
    this.labelLayerName = options.labelLayerName;

    switch (options.layerType) {
        case "polyline":
            //set options
            break;
        case "marker":
            //set options
            break;
        case "label":
            //set options
            break;
    }

    return new this.layerType(options);

};
```

When initializing a layer, i include the layer name for the labels so I can toggle each one individually, depending on visibility.

```
myLayer = new LayerFactory();
myLayer.createLayer({ map: gmap, layerType: "marker", labelLayerName: "MyLabels" });
```

Now, when toggling the layer, I just pull the layer needed and set the map to null/gmap:

```
yourMapLayer.setMap(/* gmap OR null => show/hide */);
```

I hope this helps anyone who experienced the problem I was having. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some code from [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) an MVCObject containing multiple polylines (it takes a `paths` array like a Polygon does).  Don't know if it works with dashed lines.

```
/**
 * A MultiGeometry object that will allow multiple polylines in a MultiGeometry
 * containing LineStrings to be treated as a single object
 *
 * @param {MutiGeometryOptions} anonymous object.  Available properties:
 * map: The map on which to attach the MultiGeometry
 * paths: the individual polylines
 * polylineOptions: options to use when constructing all the polylines
 *
 * @constructor
 */
// only if Google Maps API included
if (!!window.google && !! google.maps) { 
function MultiGeometry(multiGeometryOptions) {
   function createPolyline(polylineOptions, mg) {
     var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline(polylineOptions);
     google.maps.event.addListener(polyline,'click', function(evt) { google.maps.event.trigger(mg,'click',evt);});
     google.maps.event.addListener(polyline,'dblclick', function(evt) { google.maps.event.trigger(mg, 'dblclick', evt);});
     google.maps.event.addListener(polyline,'mousedown', function(evt) { google.maps.event.trigger(mg, 'mousedown', evt);});
     google.maps.event.addListener(polyline,'mousemove', function(evt) { google.maps.event.trigger(mg, 'mousemove', evt);});
     google.maps.event.addListener(polyline,'mouseout', function(evt) { google.maps.event.trigger(mg, 'mouseout', evt);});
     google.maps.event.addListener(polyline,'mouseover', function(evt) { google.maps.event.trigger(mg, 'mouseover', evt);});
     google.maps.event.addListener(polyline,'mouseup', function(evt) { google.maps.event.trigger(mg, 'mouseup', evt);});
     google.maps.event.addListener(polyline,'rightclick', function(evt) { google.maps.event.trigger(mg, 'rightclick', evt);});
     return polyline;
   }
   this.setValues(multiGeometryOptions);
   this.polylines = [];

   for (i=0; i<this.paths.length;i++) {
     var polylineOptions = multiGeometryOptions;
     polylineOptions.path = this.paths[i];
     var polyline = createPolyline(polylineOptions,this);
     // Bind the polyline properties to the MultiGeometry properties
     this.polylines.push(polyline);
   }
}
MultiGeometry.prototype = new google.maps.MVCObject();
MultiGeometry.prototype.changed = function(key) {
    // alert(key+" changed");
    if (this.polylines) {
        for (var i=0; i<this.polylines.length; i++) {
            this.polylines[i].set(key,this.get(key));
        }
    }
};
MultiGeometry.prototype.setMap = function(map) { this.set('map',map); };
MultiGeometry.prototype.getMap = function() { return this.get('map'); };
}
```

Comment: after further investigation, the multigeometry object just groups the polylines? I am looking to have them as individual entities, but within one container. Basically, i want the same behaviour as a data layer, but use polylines instead of features.

Comment: geocodezip, am I able to use the base class MVCObject and use it in a similar fashion as the MultiGeometry object, but have individual polylines?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means.  If you were to post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue, I might be able to apply it to your code.

Comment: The purpose of the MultiGeometry object was to allow a collection of separate Polylines to be controlled as one.

Comment: I modified the code to accept multiple types and bind a custom object to the type (polyline, marker, etc). When the end user clicks on the map object, I can now access properties as a feature, including toggling the entire layer (Multigeometry). Thanks for your input geocode.